# Can a className property be dynamic in formly forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

Is there a way to make formly form's field's className dynamic?

I want a field's className to change based on a variable.

For example if `vm.isTrue == true`then className: `'col-xs-2'`, else `'col-xs-5'`.

I've tried this:

```
{
    className: 'col-xs-2',
    key: 'maintenanceYN',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
          disabled: vm.locked
    },
    expressionProperties: {
          'className': function() {
                   if(vm.isTrue == true) {
                        return 'col-xs-2'
                   } else {
                        return 'col-xs-5'
                   }
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the conditional straight in the className property, as such:

```
{
    className: vm.isTrue ? 'col-xs-2' : 'col-xs-5',
    key: 'maintenanceYN',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
          disabled: vm.locked
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Tried putting a model's variable and it doesn't seem to recognize it.